# Latency to/from Xeon Phi

Tags: gpgpu, latency, pci

What is a typical latency measure for moving a "small amount" of data (like a few kb) from a CPU cache to a coprocessor like the Xeon PHI?  I assume that the return trip would take a similar amount of time, but if not, please specify that in your answer.

I know that this depends on a lot of things, but I'm just looking for order-of-magnitude numbers, and I don't have a similar setup to test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the question, as you ask it really doesn't have an answer. You can ask what the raw bandwidth and latency of a PCIe bus is, but that doesn't really tell you anything. And you wouldn't really want to read a word into cache in the processor then sending it to the coprocessor. You want to keep the processor itself out of all this as much as possible.
At a minimum, what you need to know before you can ask a question like this is what protocol am I using to move the data, where is the data and how big is the data transfer.
I could suggest you read the [Intel® Xeon Phi™ Coprocessor System Software Developers Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-system-software-developers-guide) if you want to know about the Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor in particular. (I can't speak to any other architectures - I'm ignorant there.) But the System Software Developers Guide is way more detail than you want or need at this point. But if you want a general idea of what is going on, I would tell you that the Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor mostly uses something called SCIF to communicate between the host and coprocessor and you can find out the basics in chapter six of Rezaur's book Intel® Xeon Phi™ Coprocessor Architecture and Tools: The Guide for Application Developers (which you can find on Google books if you want to just read that chapter.) 
As I say, I can't speak to any other architecture; I just don't know. But I'm sure you can find information out there.

Answer (score 0):

Data is not transferred from the host's cache to the co-processor. It can be transferred from the host's memory, to the co-processor's. 
Keep in mind that this doesn't occur in native execution. It can only be achieved in offload model.

Now, if you want to benchmark the speed of data transfer, it will depend on your motherboard, and the PCIe bus bandwidth/latency.